# Disable dates in t-datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

datepicker (https://github.com/crazychicken/t-datepicker)
and want to disable dates by check in and different dates by check out.
for example:

disable dates in check in: `['2019-09-23','2019-09-25']`

disable dates in check out: `['2019-09-29','2019-09-30']`
in the plugin there is a way to disable dates like this:

dateDisabled: `['2019-09-26','2019-09-27']`
but its disable both (check in and check out)

Comment: Are you passing the `dateDisabled` values to both of your datepicker elements? Their GitHub page has an example with two datepicker elements with different classes: `$('.class_a').tDatePicker()` and `$('.class_b').tDatePicker` - have you tried this?

Comment: my tDatePicker is on the big div that containing both .t-check-in .t-check-out
like this: jQuery('.t-datepicker').tDatePicker